# React Component Event Handler Not Fired When Another Component's Event removes rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Background: 
I am attempting to build something of an search bar with results that can be selected.
The goal is as the user types there are autocomplete values below the search bar the user can select.

Problem: 
When trying to hide the div for the autocomplete values when the input field looses focus, the set state dispatch by the click of one of the autocomplete rows is lost.

Example Code:

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false);
  
  return(
    <>
      <input 
        value={value} 
        onChange={e => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)} 
        onFocus={() => setFocused(true)} 
        onBlur={() => setFocused(false)} 
      />
      {focused && (
        <div>
          <div className="item" onClick={() => setValue("item 1")} >item 1 </div>
          <div className="item" onClick={() => setValue("item 2")} >item 2 </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codepen.io/cashire/pen/WNYgpqK

If you click on `item I` or `item 2` after focusing the input, the input never has its state changed.

From what I have been able to ascertain, the item's `onClick` handler is never called because of the onBlur is processed first and its set state dispatch somehow causes react to ignore the `onClick` event. Ideally, if the `onClick` fired first it would work. My hope was the `onClick` event would happen before the next render but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Question: 
How would I go about getting around this event race condition and allow me to have both events to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your "focus" to false on the click of `Item 1` and `Item 2` rather than `onBlur` from the `<input>`.  You can do this by using the `||` operator, allowing you to fire two functions, setting two separate hooks in a single click:

```
  return(
    <>
      <input 
        defaultValue={value} 
        onChange={e => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)} 
        onFocus={() => setFocused(true)} 
        // onBlur={() => setFocused(false)} 
      />
      {focused && (
        <div>
          <div className="item" onClick={() => setValue("item 1") || setFocused(false)}>item 1 </div>
          <div className="item" onClick={() => setValue("item 2") || setFocused(false)}>item 2 </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

**With that said** ... I would recommend changing the nomenclature of your hook to read something more like `showSearchValues` since it's not really the "focus" of your input you care about, but when and how to show your search terms.  The only reason I recommend this, is it can help change your thinking about what the handlers you are using (onClick, onBlur) can do *for* you, rather than thinking of them as a *state* (focused, clicked).

```
 const [showSearchValues, setShowSearchValues] = React.useState(false);
```

and

```
<div className="item" onClick={() => setValue("item 1") || setShowSearchValues(false)}>item 1 </div>
```

and

```
onFocus={() => setShowSearchValues(true)}
```

and

```
{showSearchValues && (
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of when the input loses focus I want to close the search. If the user doesn't select an item, but instead, tabs away or clicks away the items stay visible. This is why I was using on blur to close them.